# Python to iOS Application

Tags: python, ios

I have created a large application as part of a project I am working on and have created it using python and is only a console application.

I have been able to convert the python project into a windows executable but also want to convert this to work as an iPhone/iPad application. Is there any way of converting the application to work as an iOS application? Or am I best re-writing the application using something like XCode?

The application uses paramiko for ssh and some mysql commands so uses external libraries.

Please could someone give me some guidance

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rewrite your application, you could try [kivy](https://kivy.org/#home).

It is pretty well supported.